# print tn.read_all() does not return anything in telnetlib python script

Tags: python, cisco, telnetlib

I am trying to telnet into a cisco ios-xr router and gather command output.

I have tested that the below code successfully connects to the router and executes the command, however it seems that neither `print tn.read_all()` nor `tn.read_very_eager()` works. They do not print anything. Am I missing anything obvious here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import telnetlib
import time 

HOST = "10.62.53.34"
PORT = "17006"
user = "cisco"
password = "cisco"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT)
print "Telnetting to", HOST, "@",PORT
tn.write("\n")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.write(password + "\n")
#print("I am in")
tn.write("show runn\n")
tn.write("exit \n")
print tn.read_all()
tn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

though this question is from february, i'll post my answer for a potential future googler.

i fixed a similar problem when i realized that:

```
print tn.read_all()
```

...is valid in python 2 (see the example at the bottom of https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html), but not in python 3 (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/telnetlib.html).

for python 3, the correct syntax would be:

```
print(tn.read_all())
```